# Validating and highlighting a form fields

Tags: adobe, pdf-form, livecycle-designer

I have a form, with a lot of fields, which must be NOT blank. And they must NOT be highlighted.
So, on the one hand: i have to make these fields required, for don't let users print the form with blank fields. But if I’ll do it with standard settings, the fields will be highlighted with a red color (default settings of the acrobat reader). Yes, these settings can be changed in Acrobat Reader, but as the form will be used by a lot of users - i can't force them all change their settings.
On the other hand: If the form fields are set to be optional, then validation scripts don't work on empty fields.
So, is there any ways to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

This is a curveball requirement. Generally, clients actually want some kind of a visible indicator in  the form fields to bring their attention to a specific field. I would recommend reviewing the requirements as it goes against usability guides and industry best practices.

Having said that, there is away to achieve what you are trying to Achieve.

1. Open up the form you are working on and navigate to :
   File > Form Properties > Form Validation > Color Mandatory Fields
2. Select the checkbox: "Color Mandatory Fields that are not filled in" and select a white color from the color picker "Border Color" and "Background Color" properties.

Please let me know if you have any questions.

Thanks,
Armaghan.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Armaghan with regards to usability and best practice.
If highlighing the field isn't an option then you could set the focus to the field by looping through each required field and when it hits one that is incomplete, stop and give the field focus.  This is far from ideal because if the user has missed a number of fields, they will have to go through the same process for each one until done.  It would also mean adding a check my form button to instigate the validation check.